# omp, more threads more slowly

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I just added a `omp pragma` to parallel this `for` loop, but more threads make it more slowly.
I tried schedules `auto`, `guide, 10`, `static, 10`.

One thread needs 4 min, 2 need 6 min, more threads are more slowly...

I'm not familiar with `omp`, so anyone help ...

This function is called often, so I print `pairs.size()`, sometimes it's 0, sometimes it's 498.
I think it maybe that each iteration's work is so small that the threads operation cost too much time..

```
fl eval_pairs_deriv(const precalculate& p, fl v, const interacting_pairs& pairs,
                    const vecv& coords, vecv& forces) {

    const fl cutoff_sqr = p.cutoff_sqr();
    fl e = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+ : e) schedule(runtime)
    for (int i = 0; i < (pairs).size(); ++(i)) {
        const interacting_pair& ip = pairs[i];

        vec r;
        r = coords[ip.b] - coords[ip.a]; // a -> b
        fl r2 = sqr(r);
        // f1 tt=0;
        double tt = 0;
        if (r2 < cutoff_sqr) {
            pr tmp = p.eval_deriv(ip.type_pair_index, r2);
            vec force;
            force = tmp.second * r;
            curl(tmp.first, force, v);
            tt = tmp.first;
            forces[ip.a] -= force;
            forces[ip.b] += force;
        }
        e += tt;
    }

    return e;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you could clean up some of your grammar on this post, it might do better. It's kind of hard to understand at the moment.

Comment: #pragma omp atomic      

    forces[ip.a] -= force;     
error: Illegal operation in atomic expression

Comment: When learning OpenMP always specify the accessibility of variables (shared or private) in parallel sections.  Don't rely on defaults.  Specify the accessibility and understand what your code is doing inside the parallel sections.

Comment: I assume by the name that `forces` is a vector like (continuous memory) container if that is the case, you could have a case of false sharing (if pairs.size() is big enough), when a thread invalidate the cache line when updating `forces[ip.a] -= force;` and/or `forces[ip.b] += force;`, forcing to reload again the memory in the cache for all the thread accessing.

Comment: There may not only be **false sharing** as pointed out by NetVipeC, but also a **race condition** on `forces[]` when your omp parallel code actually fails. Regarding the timing, you may well be correct in assuming that the work you're trying to share is too little to make it worthwhile given the overheads for generating & managing the parallel threads. You can find out by increasing `pairs.size()`.

Comment: How many processors does your computer have? Have you check how many processors your current computer is using? I suggest you call the function omp_get_num_threads() and find out how many processors are currently being used by the computer. If its only one then there is no performance change, however if the CPU is utilizing all of your processors then you need to check your code.

Comment: To answer your question you need to provide more information. Does ip.a and ip.b always return unique values as a function of `i`. Are the values monotonically increasing/decreasing as a function of `i`? Do you get the same result with one thread as with multiple threads? What happens when you comment out the lines that write to `force`?